# TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__' for palindrome

Tags: python

I am trying to create a palindrome without using a reverse function:
Below is my code

```
    import sys
    print (sys.argv)
    arg=len(sys.argv)


# check to determine if there is more than one argument on the command line

    if len(sys.argv) !=2:
       print("Specify 1 argument")

    else:
       statement=sys.argv[1]

#remove any space in the statement
    list=[]

for info in statement:
    if info == " ":
        list.append(info)
# create one string variable
    string="".join(list)

# make string lower case 
    string_lower=string.islower()

# reversing list 
    reverse_lower = string_lower[::-1]

# compare the orginal list to the reverse list 
    if (string_lower == reverse_lower):
       print("It's a palindrome!")
    else:
       print("It's not a palindrome!")
```

I get an error stating:

reverse_lower=string_lower[::-1]
TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Any help would be beneficial

Comment: Incorrect function called to make string lower case. User lower() instead of islower()

Answer (score 2):

The .islower() Method returns a bool that says if the given string is only lowercase, you want .lower()

Comment: Thank you the error goes away but I am having issues with my strings not being compared

Answer (score 0):

.islower returns True or False, .lower() returns the actual string:

```
>>> 'a'.islower()
True
>>> 'a'.lower()
'a'
```

[::-1] returns a string. When you try to compare the string and the boolean, your error arises.